# sdkmanager connection timeout ubuntu

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu, networking

so i am very new at flutter development so when i try to installl flutter as well as Android studio i get some errors
so basically what i have done is,
first i downloaded the latest android studio from official site it gives
[image: this error]

so i installed command line SDK tools from official website
i add it to my path and also i have changes the file structure like `/home/somen/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`
so it is on my path and gives this error
[image: sdkmanager error]

basically it's saying connection time out and failed to Download any source list,
also i am using zorin os based on ubuntu and there is no firewall also checked ping on download links it works but sdkmanager don't also i used androidsdk a wrapper for sdkmanager from snapstore

```
somen@somen-desktop:~/Downloads/android-studio/bin$ sudo ./studio.sh 
2023-05-13 18:22:45,388 [   9928]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk] 
2023-05-13 18:22:57,127 [  21667]   WARN - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - UI freezed for 10220ms, details saved to /root/.AndroidStudioPreview4.1/system/log/threadDumps-freeze-20230513-182246-AI-193.6494.35.41.6325121-PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect-10sec 
2023-05-13 18:27:38,944 [ 303484]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Failed to download any source lists! 
2023-05-13 18:27:48,950 [ 313490]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely. 
2023-05-13 18:27:48,960 [ 313500]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - IO exception while downloading manifest 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.openConnection(HttpRequests.java:607)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$300(HttpRequests.java:56)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getConnection(HttpRequests.java:376)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.lambda$doDownloadFully$2(StudioDownloader.java:197)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:518)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:500)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:56)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.doDownloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:250)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadAndStream(StudioDownloader.java:123)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.lambda$fetchPackages$0(RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-05-13 18:27:49,950 [ 314490]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely..
```

this is the error logs when i try in Android studio itself in sdk maneger Tab in settings.
please help,and ask me if you need any clarification.